# Cant send email on my local host why?

Tags: c#

Why cant I send email on my localhost I get this error: The SMTP host was not specified

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("fromEmail@email.com","toEmail@email.com", "Test", "Test Body");
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();

            client.Send(mail);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **The SMTP host was not specified**

Comment: use your isp or host's smtp server

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to mail with your "localhost"

Try with:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("localhost", 25);
```

If not:

If the mail server is not on your localhost specify the smtp client **ipAddress** 
or hostname and the smtp service **port**.

**EDIT: Here you have some example code to send mail with gmail:**

```
SmtpClient clientesmtp = GetSmtpClient();
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com", "to@gmail.com", "Subject","body");
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
clientesmtp.Send(msg);           

private static SmtpClient GetSmtpClient()
{
SmtpClient clientesmtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
clientesmtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
clientesmtp.EnableSsl = true;
return clientesmtp;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a mail server installed on the computer where the application is running?. Are you trying to send some email through gmail or something like that?

Comment: @Hello-World: have you set a local smtp in IIS?

Comment: What is wrong is that you need a smtp service to send mail. You can use public servers like gmail but if you have not a smtp service installed on the machine you will never send an email connecting localhost. You have to specify the server ip, user account, password and create the mailmessage to send through the server.

Comment: @Hello-World [How Does An Email Server Work?](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/technology-explained-how-does-an-email-server-work/)

Comment: I edited the post to show you an example to send email with GMAIL. Maybe it help you

Answer (score 1):

By default, the SMTPClient [will use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1c4h6e2.aspx) the host and port defined in `<mailSettings>` from the application or machine.config file.

> This constructor initializes the Host, Credentials, and Port properties for the new SmtpClient by using the settings in the application or machine configuration files.

The [defaults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx) for *those* are `localhost:25`. However, you may have edited your machine.config to remove that host.

You can either edit your application.config or machine.config to include an appropriate mailSettings attribute or specify the appropriate values in code.

Naturally, you will need to have an SMTP server actually running on localhost, but from your question I assume you do?