# How to send mail from local server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

I am using smtp in codeigniter and i tried this code.

```
$config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
                'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', // change it to yours
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
              );
                $this->load->library('email', $config);
                $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');
                $this->email->from('email@email.com', 'Testing');
                $this->email->reply_to('email@email.com', 'Testing');
                $this->email->to('email@email.com');
                $this->email->cc('email@email.com');
                $this->email->subject('Testing');
                $this->email->message($message);
                $this->email->send();
```

But i didnt understand what smtp_user and smtp_pass i have to give. Can anyone tel me!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant send email on my local host why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376362/cant-send-email-on-my-local-host-why)

Comment: ur gmail's username and password that's it

Comment: i applied but still mail is not receiving, i am using wamp server, is there any changes in configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The smtp_user adn smtp_pass are your username and passwod for your gmail account. Please read this document https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server